# c++ finding argmax of vector from specific indices

Tags: c++, vector, argmax

from here, i know that we can get the `argmax` of a `vector like this:

```cpp
vector<int> v{ 3, 1, -14, 1, 5, 9 }; 
vector<int>::iterator result = max_element(v.begin(), v.end());
int argmaxVal = distance(v.begin(), result);
// argmaxVal = 5 because v[5] = 9
```

How do i get the `argmax` of vector from index 2 to 4?
Or, in general, from index k to index n, (assumed to be contiguous).

```cpp
// argmaxVal = 4 because v[4] = 5
// which is max of v[2], v[3], v[4]
```

Obviously i can do it like this:

```cpp
int VectorArgMax(vector<> v, int start_idx, int end_idx){
    int retVal = start_idx;
    for (int idx=start_idx; idx<=end_idx; idx++){
        if v[idx] > v[retVal]{
            retVal = idx;
        }
    }
    return retVal;
}
result = VectorArgMax(v,2,4);
```

But is using `max_element` and `distance` faster, or any even faster function I can use directly?

Comment: Are the specific indices always contiguous? Also, `max_element` doesn't return a `vector`, and your function signature syntax is incorrect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply adjust the input iterators to `std::max_element`:

```
std::vector<int>::iterator max = max_element(v.begin() + 2, v.begin() + 4); // [2, 4)
int argmaxVal = distance(v.begin(), max); // absolute index of max
```

You can also replace `std::vector<int>::iterator` with `auto` for convenience with `C++11`.

Comment: @cigien Right, I'm trying to make it explicit since OP used `std::vector<int>`